# User gesture within confirm dialog

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am making a Chrome extension. I need it to downloading open the file, but i have error

> Unchecked runtime.lastError: User gesture required

manifest v 3:

```
 "permissions": [ "notifications", "contextMenus", "storage" , "clipboardWrite", "tabs", "activeTab", "scripting", "downloads", "downloads.open", "downloads.shelf"],
```

background.js:

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    id: "reg",
    title: "Open link",
    contexts: ["link"]
});
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener((info, tab) => {
    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
        target: { tabId: tab.id, frameIds: [info.frameId] },
        files: ['myscript.js'],
    });
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
        function gool(request, sender) {
            let conf = request.x
            console.log(conf)
            chrome.downloads.download({
                url: info.linkUrl,
            });
            chrome.downloads.onChanged.addListener(function (downloadId) {
                if (downloadId.state.current == "complete") {
                    if (conf == true) {
                        chrome.downloads.open(downloadId.id)                            
                    }
                }
            })             
        }
    );
})
```

myscript.js:

```
{
var x = confirm("hello")
       chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ x })
}
```

I think if confirm == true it is my gesture for open my file (downloads.open)
Why its not work?

Comment: As far as i know, "user gesture" usually means the user has to click/press something which causes some code to run which downloads the file. Your file downloading code might be too far away from the user gesture.

Comment: How i can gesture within confirm dialog?